# Why are entanglement and purity non-linear functions of $\rho$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, observables

Any linear function of the density matrix can be related to a proper observable, but is it not the case of entanglement and purity?

Comment: What do you mean by linear in $\rho$? Does it mean it is linear on the matrix elements $\langle m \vert \rho \vert n \rangle$? If so, then one clue to why entanglement needs to be more than linear is because it relates to a correlation between different entries of a density matrix, roughly saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that entanglement cannot be related to linear observables on the system: An *entanglement witness* $W$ is a linear operator such that 
whenever the expectation value 
$$
\mathrm{tr}[W\rho]<0\ ,
$$
the state must be entangled.   Thus, the presence of entanglement can be detected by a measurement of $W$.

(Caveat: Note that this only works if we have some prior information about $\rho$, since any witness will only detect a part of all entangled states.  This is due to the convex structure of the set of non-entangled states, and the fact that $\mathrm{tr}[W\rho]=\mathrm{const.}$ defines a hyperplane.)

Answer (score 1):

One way to interpret your question is that you ask why there is no (linear) measurement which allows to see whether a given state $\rho$ is mixed, or how mixed it is.  This relates both to the purity, and to the entanglement -- *if* by "entanglement" you mean "identifying if (and how much) a pure bipartite state is entangled by looking at the reduced density operator of one party".

Consider a mixed state $\rho$, and an observable $M$.  Let us express both in the eigenbasis $\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\vert#1\rangle}\ket{i}$ of $M$: $M=\sum m_i \ket{i}\langle i|$, $\rho=\sum \rho_{ij} \ket{i}\langle j|$.

Then, $$\mathrm{tr}[M\rho] = \sum m_i \langle i\vert \rho \ket{i} = \sum m_i \rho_{ii}\ .$$ But if we instead take the state 
$$
\ket\psi = \sum \sqrt{\rho_{ii}}\ket{i}\ ,
$$
 we also have that
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{tr}[M\ket\psi\langle\psi|] &= \langle \psi \vert M \ket\psi \\ 
& = \sum m_i \langle\psi\ket i \langle i\ket\psi  
\\
& = \sum m_i \rho_{ii}\ .
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the pure state $\ket\psi$ yields just the same expectation value as $\rho$ for the given observable $M$, and thus, there cannot be an observable $M$ which can tell whether a state is pure or mixed.

(*Note: I have posted this as a separate answer as it is orthogonal to the other answer - both in the way it interprets the question, and the answer itself.*)

Comment: Congratulations on reaching 10k!

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks (-: